# Hibernate search and range query on BigDecimal

Tags: java, hibernate, search, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm having a hard time designing a query to search all instances of Item class with price between 100 and 200.

Here is my Item class:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id @DocumentId
    Long id

    @Field(index = Index.UN_TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
    @NumericField
    @FieldBridge(impl = BigDecimalNumericFieldBridge.class)
    BigDecimal price = BigDecimal.ZERO
}
```

BigDecimalNumericFieldBridge being the class described here: https://hibernate.onjira.com/secure/attachment/15952/proposed_doc.txt

Luke shows me that I have several documents whose price is between 100 and 200.

Here is my query:

```
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
final QueryBuilder queryBuilder =     fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Item).get();

Query rootQuery = queryBuilder.bool()
    .must(queryBuilder.range().onField('price').above(100).createQuery())
    .must(queryBuilder.range().onField('price').below(200).createQuery())
    .createQuery();

FullTextQuery ftq = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(rootQuery, Item);
List<Item> instanceList = ftq.list();
```

But the list is always empty, no matter the bounds. 
Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

By the way, I'm using Hibernate Search 3.4.1 with Hibernate 3.6.10.

Answer (score 5):

As a matter of fact, there was an error in the way I do my query. Hibernate Search being type-specific, and my values being stored as longs, I need to query with longs too. And I have to multiply values by 100 because that's the multiplier in the bridge:

```
Query rootQuery = queryBuilder.bool()
    .must(queryBuilder.range().onField('price').above(10000L).createQuery())
    .must(queryBuilder.range().onField('price').below(20000L).createQuery())
    .createQuery();
```

For a more detailed answer with a unit test, see this post on Hibernate forums: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2457657#p2457657